# two divs side by side with each having 100% width off the screen

Tags: html, css

I have two divs named A and B and I want to show them side by side as shown in the image below:

[image]

I have tried this css, which does not work:

```
.A, .B {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: when you say "which does not work" - it does not really describe what the issue is. Can you elaborate more? and add a [mcve] to your question?

Comment: try `.parent { white-space: nowrap; }`

Comment: @SeanDenny Can you please post it as answer? It works like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `white-space` CSS property, you can achieve this with `nowrap`. From [`white-space` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

> `nowrap`: Collapses whitespace as for normal, but suppresses line breaks (text wrapping) within the source

```
.parent {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use flex for this. And set flex-wrap: no-wrap; Then main div will not break if you take more then one div as a child. And it will also make a horizontal scroll to scroll between div.

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  }
.full {
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 100px;
  line-height: 120px;
  }
.full.a {
  background-color: red;
  }
.full.b {
  background-color: blue;
  }
.full.c {
  background-color: green;
  }
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="full a">a</div>
  <div class="full b">b</div>
  <div class="full c">c</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap those divs in another div and set `width: calc(100% * 2)`

Use for `.A` and `.B` a width of `50%`

```css
.A, .B {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    float:left;
}

.A {
  background-color: red;
}

.B {
  background-color: blue;
}

.wrap {
  width: calc(100% * 2);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="A">A</div>
  <div class="B">B</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a little bit of js to measure the `innerWidth` of the window. Then use that value to set `left` on the B div:

```js
var div = document.querySelector('.b');
div.style.left = window.innerWidth + 'px';
console.log(div)
```

```css
.a, .b, body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.a {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: red;
}

.b {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
```

Use Inspect Element in the editor and you will see that B is full width outside of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a container for the `div`s (with a specified size, maybe even make it responsive) and put your `div` inside it.

Kind of like this:

```css
.A {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid green; /* you can remove this, used only to illustrate divs */
  display: inline-block;
}

.container {
  width: 2040px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="A">A</div>
  <div class="A">B</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use that

```
<div class=wrapper>
  <div class="testa"></div>
<div class="testb"></div>
</div>
```

and css

```
.testa {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  background:red;
  display:inline-block;


}
.testb {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  background:green;
  display:inline-block;

}
.wrapper {
  position:relative;
  overflow-x:auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```